# GKE Cluster doesn't gc replicasets after deleting deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After upgrading from 1.14.something then to 1.15.something then to 1.16.13-gke.1.

It started behaving weird. When I delete Deployment replicasets and pods don't get garbage collected.

Also cronjob spams with pods to the point I exceeded a quota and cannot deploy anything anymore even tho I deleted all those pods.

It had 2-4 copies of every system replicasets.

Comment: What output you will get when you use `$ kubectl get rs --all-namespaces`? Could you share your `Deployment` and `Job` YAMLs as there might be some differences in syntax. I assume you still have this issue? Did you get any errors when you tried to delete `replicaset` and `deployment` and apply it again?

Answer (score 0):

Check events for possible errors. Raise this issue in gcp or your provider.
Deployments track replica set and pods by labels and selectors. May be those got changed somehow.

Comment: everything is fine with labels, events where? deployments that I delete are alright.
how do I raise issue in gcp?

Comment: kubectl get events -n your_namespace. You can contact GCP support team.

Comment: Nothing interesting in events, I only see billing support. I guess I don't have a support in my plan

Comment: This was a bug https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34052